# JavaScript regex: why is alternation not ordered?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this code:

```js
const regex = /graph|photograph/;
'A photograph'.match(regex);
// Output: [ 'photograph', index: 2, input: 'A photograph', groups: undefined ]
```

Why is the engine not finding `graph` first? After looking at similar SO questions and the [ECMAScript docs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-disjunction), I can see that

> The `|` regular expression operator separates two alternatives. The pattern first tries to match the left *Alternative* (followed by the sequel of the regular expression); if it fails, it tries to match the right *Disjunction* (followed by the sequel of the regular expression).

Now, the above quote covers the case `/photo|photograph/` where the alternatives share a common beginning, but the case where they share a common ending appears to be governed by a different rule.

I am content with the result I am getting, as in my use case I prefer to get the longest match, not the earliest one, but I would like to know why this happens, so I can be sure this isn't just a coincidence that is bound to change in the future.

Comment: The string is parsed from left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative `graph` does not match starting at the third character, but the alternative `photograph` does. The engine proceeds through the string from left to right.

The ordering you refer to in the question applies when alternatives match from a common starting point in the string. Otherwise, while proceeding through the "haystack" string, the alternatives are *all* considered. If there's a single match starting from a particular character,
then the rest of the regex will proceed with that (and may of course backtrack later).

Whether the engine prefers longer matches from a set of alternatives when there are multiple matches from the same character in the source, I can't say off the top of my head. I would guess it would try the longer one first, to consume more of the string optimistically, because it can always backtrack. However, I don't know that to be actual specified behavior and just thinking about reading the regex semantics in the spec makes my head hurt.